# Clogged upstairs sink and tub faucets

Tags: plumbing

The pipes in my 1st floor bathroom needed extending due to the installation of a new vanity.  After water was turned back on and plumber left, the upstairs faucets were clogged.  I removed the screen from the sink faucet and found what looked like pipe dope.  Now the shower has no pressure and the valves feel gritty when turned. What could have caused this?

And the line runs straight up from the first floor sink to the second floor sink.

Comment: I have not used pipe dope, but I imagine it is brushed onto the threads like the wrap.  Unless the plumber just dipped the pipe into the dope, there should not be dope in the lines.  I can see turning off/on the water would disturb sediment and cause clogging/feeling gritty

Comment: Call the plumber back.  He could have left anything in the pipe.  Or remove the  faucets and see if you can spot the blockage.